# How to show weblog categories in foreach in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a Category and Weblog for my website.

This is Category Model :

```
public function weblogs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Weblog::class);
}
```

And this is Weblog Model :

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

As you can see there is a realation between Weblog and Category.

This is Controller :

```
$weblogs = Weblog::paginate(9);
return view('index', compact('weblogs'));
```

And this is my blade for showing weblog items :

```
@foreach($weblogs as $weblog)
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="blog-item">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="#"><img alt=""
                                         src="/Weblog/image/{{ $weblog->image }}"></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4><a href="#">{{ $weblog->name }}</a></h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">{{ jdate($weblog->created_at)->format('%d %B %Y') }}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">سبک زندگی</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="blog-btn">
                        <a href="#" class="btn-st">بیشتر بخوانید</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
@endforeach
```

I want to show category belong to any item of weblog, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access property in your template

```
<div class="blog-item">
    ...
    @foreach ($weblog->categories as $category)
      {{ $category }}
    @endforeach
    ...
</div>
```

You can also load relations earlier

```php
$weblogs = Weblogs::with('categories')->paginate(9)
```

You can read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties and here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading